# When to create multi thread Vs when to create multiple process?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, operating-system, computer-science

I have a 4 core PC. I can either create 4 threads in my code for parallel execution or I can create 4 process using fork() in my program. I am not sure whether to go for multiple threads or multiple processes. Please explain when to use what.

Comment: At the OS level, the scheduling unit is usually the thread. So for scheduling reasons, it doesn't matter. What matter is if you want to easily share memory or not. Threads in a process can easily communicate through global variables, shares handles and file descriptors. They all see the same view of memory. Processes are completely separated from each other by default. Generally speaking: use processes if 1) you want to make sure that a crash in a thread only affects it (or its group). 2) it's easier to duplicate some structures rather than share them (e.g. the Python interpreter with its GIL)

Comment: Additionally, processes can be a good idea for isolation/security. Browsers mostly now use multiple processes because of that: if one process crash, others are left unaffected while if 1 thread crash, then all the threads of the same processes are KO. Besides specifying the language should be a good idea. Interpreters often have limited threads that are not truly parallel (eg. AFAIK Python and R for example). In general, unless you have some unusual requirements, threads are the way to go (eg in C/C++/Java for example).